# Zk decimalbox tooltiptext dynamically

Tags: java, ria, zk

I have a simple

```
<decimalbox tooltiptext='@{createToolTip()}'/>
```

The tooltip for the decimalbox i want to be dynamically `generated every time is requested` generated and is returned from a method createToolTip() in this case..... the onCreate method dont work for me because the value of the tooltiptext may change after the component is create..

what can i do

the Code above is not working...

I'm missing something?

Best regards from Venezuela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are using a load once method with is not dynamicly.

Use for MVVM:

```
<decimalbox tooltiptext="@load(vm.createToolTip())"/>
```

For MVC I suggest putting a listener(when your tooltiptext has to change) and alter the tooltiptext in java code.
Normally the method is in your Controller so you can autowire the decimalbox and change the tooltip.
If that is not the case, provide a little more info from where the method comes.

Example in fiddle : http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3hjk8af/6-decimalbox-tooltip

**Note:** For answering this question, I gave same answer as I gave on the ZK-forum, witch was marked as solution.